# xfce4-panel not showing up after switching video cards

Tags: xfce, video

I recently changed video cards and now my xfce4-panel isn't showing up.  I've checked the process list and found that xfce4-panel is running and I've tried restarting it. I made no other changes other than switching video cards and had a working config before.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you panel is set to go to a specific video port that you're not using anymore. If you can open a terminal window, then you can start the xfce4-settings-manager and check what output the panel is set to go to.

```
xfce4-settings-manager
```

Then click on `Panel`. Under the `Output` setting see if it's set to something specific like `DP1` or `HDMI0`, if so, try changing that setting to `Primary` or `Automatic` and see if your panel reappears. It should happen instantly once you change it.

In my case, I got rid of using my display port and switched back to an HDMI port, but my output setting was set to specifically `DP1`.